# What is a Baguette Word™?

Tags: pattern, english, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Baguette Word™**.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

$
\begin{gather*}
% set Title text. (spaces around the text ARE important; do not remove.)
% increase Pad value only if your entries are longer than the title bar.
%
\def\Pad{\P{0.0}}
%
\def\S#1#2{\Space{#1}{20px}{#2px}}\def\P#1{\V{#1em}}\def\V#1{\S{#1}{9}}
\def\T{\textbf{Baguette Words}^{\;\!™}\Pad}\def\NT{\Pad\textbf{Not Baguette Words}^{\;\!™}\Pad\ }
\smash{\lower{29px}\bbox[lightblue]{\phantom{\rlap{rubio.2019.05.15}\S{6px}{0}
\begin{array}{cc}\Pad\T&\NT\\\end{array}}}}\atop\def\V#1{\S{#1}{5}}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\Pad\T&\NT\\\hline
%
\text{  vase}&\text{       bowl}\\ \hline
\text{  abandon}&\text{       leave}\\ \hline
\text{  announce}&\text{       declare}\\ \hline
\text{  Canada}&\text{       Singapore}\\ \hline
\text{  air}&\text{       wind}\\ \hline
\text{  exchange}&\text{       stack}\\ \hline
\text{  algorithm}&\text{       mathematics}\\ \hline
\text{  legend}&\text{       myth}\\ \hline
\text{  fork}&\text{       knife}\\ \hline
\text{  address}&\text{       location}\\ \hline
\text{  adorable}&\text{       cute}\\ \hline
\hline
\end{array}
\end{gather*}$

These are not the only examples of Baguette Words™.

CSV version:

```
Baguette Words™,  Not Baguette Words™
vase,           bowl
abandon,        leave
announce,       declare
Canada,         Singapore
air,            wind
exchange,       stack
algorithm,      mathematics
legend,         myth
fork,           knife
address,        location
adorable,       cute
```

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

Hint 1:

> a6d

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is:

> A Baguette Word™ is a word that has a French origin.

Reasoning:

> (All the etymologies stated below are from googling "(word) etymology" unless stated otherwise)
>
> For the Baguette Words™:
> **vase**: late Middle English: **from French**, from Latin vas ‘vessel’.
> **abandon**: late Middle English: **from Old French** abandoner, ...
> **announce**: late 15th century: **from French** annoncer, from Latin annuntiare, ...
> **Canada**: from Wiktionary: "**From French** Canada, from the Laurentian kanata (“village, settlement”)."
> **air**: Middle English (in air (sense 1 of the noun)): **from Old French** air, from Latin aer,...
> **exchange**: late Middle English: **from Old French** eschange (noun), eschangier (verb), based on changer (see change)...
> **algorithm**: late 17th century (...): variant (...) of Middle English algorism, **via Old French** from medieval Latin algorismus .
> **legend**: Middle English (in the sense ‘story of a saint's life’): **from Old French** legende, from medieval Latin legenda ‘things to be read’, from Latin legere ‘read’.
> **fork**: Old English forca, force (denoting a farm implement), based on Latin furca ‘pitchfork, forked stick’; reinforced in Middle English by **Anglo-Norman French** furke (also from Latin furca ).
> **address**: Middle English (as a verb ...): **from Old French**, based on Latin ad- ‘towards’ + directus (see direct). ...
> **adorable**: early 17th century (in the sense ‘worthy of divine worship’): **from French**, from Latin adorabilis, from the verb adorare (see adore).
>
> For the Not Baguette Words™:
> **bowl**: Old English bolle, bolla, of Germanic origin; related to Dutch bol ‘round object’, also to boll.
> **leave**: Old English lǣfan ‘bequeath’, also ‘allow to remain, leave in place’ of Germanic origin; related to German bleiben ‘remain’.
> **declare**: Middle English: from Latin declarare, from de- ‘thoroughly’ + clarare ‘make clear’ (from clarus ‘clear’).
> **Singapore**: from Wiktionary: "From Malay Singapura, from Sanskrit सिंहपुर (siṃhá-pura), from सिंह (siṃha, “lion”) +‎ पुर (pura, “city”). "
> **wind**: Old English, of Germanic origin; related to Dutch wind and German Wind, from an Indo-European root shared by Latin ventus .
> **stack**: Middle English: from Old Norse stakkr ‘haystack’, of Germanic origin.
> **mathematics**: While both google and Wiktionary state the word hes a French origin, etymonline.com gives: "from Old French mathematique and directly from Latin mathematica (plural), ...", so perhaps the problem designer thinks the word is directly from Latin?
> **myth**: mid 19th century: from modern Latin mythus, via late Latin from Greek muthos .
> **knife**: late Old English cnīf, from Old Norse knífr, of Germanic origin.
> **location**: late 16th century: from Latin locatio(n- ), from the verb locare (see locate).
> **cute**: early 18th century (in the sense ‘clever, shrewd’): shortening of acute.
> With no "French" in sight (except for "mathematics": see above).

It is called Baguette Word™ because:

> "Baguette" is usually taken as pertaining to French culture.

As for the hint:

> a6d is a French youtuber.

Comment: Great job! Good thinking